# Convert PHP Output to PDF

Tags: php, jquery, pdf

I have a PHP file which includes data from a MySQL database.  How can I convert the output of the PHP script to a PDF

File #1:

```
<?php
require(path . "/includes/header.php"); //header for html
require(path . "/includes/database.php"); //database settings

$c_id = $_GET['id']; //id for query;

$c_name="";
$c_image=array();


$sql1 = "SELECT cr_name FROM cr WHERE cr_id=$c_id";

$sql2 = "SELECT ci.cr_image FROM cr_image ci INNER JOIN cr_image_rel cir ON ci.cr_image_id = cir.cr_image_id WHERE cir.cr_id=$c_id";


    if ($result = $dbLink->query($sql1)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            $c_name = $row[0];  
        }
    }

    if ($result = $dbLink->query($sql2)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            array_push($c_image,$row[0]);
        }
    }      
?>
<div id="c_detail">
    <div class="info_section">
        <h2 class="section_title">Crop</h2>
        <?php 
            echo '<h3>' . $c_name . '</h3>'; 
        ?>
        <div>
                <?php                    
                    foreach ($c_image as $i=>$v){                
                        echo '<a class="c_thumb_image" title="Image Preview" href="user_image/' . $v . '"><img src="user_image/thumb_' . $v . '"/></a>';
                    }
                ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
    $dbLink->close();
?>
```

I want to create/convert File #1's output to PDF using PHP, jQuery, or anything suitable?  I have already tried using `tcpdf`, but it is not working...

```
<?php
....
....
$html = stripslashes(read("crop_detail.php", $vars));

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->Output('example_006.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

The PDF rendered, but there was no content; the page was blank!

Any suggestions?

Comment: WHAT ??? can you please expand on what the file contains ? there are lots of ways to create PDFs in PHP - google is your friend

Comment: if you have root access on the server, you could use XSL-FO by apache. For more informations http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Stylesheet_Language_%E2%80%93_Formatting_Objects

Comment: @ManseUK Google leads here.

Answer (score 3):

WKHTMLTOPDF is a great tool that will take any webpage and create a PDF. There is an example php wrapper on the website http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/. It uses the webkit rendering engine, as such it is fairly robust/accurate.

Comment: I agree that WKHTMLTOPDF is a very reliable option, and you have a lot of control over the ouput. Just remember to use HTML newpage tags when you want a new page to start (most people aren't familiar with this since it isn't used on web sites very often.)

Comment: I used the CSS `page-break-*` property to define pages on a recent project. I.e. `<div style="page-break-before:always"></div>` (not to say I would encourage use of inline styles).

Comment: Actually I meant the CSS style, I thought it was HTML there for some reason (bad memory).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could look into FPDF here: http://www.fpdf.org/

The documentation is easy enough to follow; you just include the FPDF class and start building your PDF.

Comment: I read fpdf. but I did not find how I can send a php file to get output.

Comment: I did not find any example which can generate pdf from external php